# Find the largest subset of $S=\{1,2,3,....,20\}$ such that its no two elements differ by $4$ or $7$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

**Problem :-**  Consider a subset of $S=\{1,2,3,....,20\}$ with the property that no two elements of this subset differ by $4$ or $7$. What is the largest number of elements this subset can have?

**My attempt :-**

**Case 1:-** Considering the elements from start

$1,2,3,4,12,13,14,15$ - this gives me $8$ elements

**Case 2:-** Considering the elements from end

$6,7,8,9,17,18,19,20$ - this too gives $8$ elements

The answer given is $10$ elements.  What would be the logical way to arrive at the answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fill the numbers in ascending order in a table of $7$ columns.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ \hline
15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 &  \\ 
\end{array}

To avoid choosing numbers differing by $7$, we should not pick from same column and immediate rows. To select maximum of numbers, we pick from first and third rows. Your examples fail due to consecutive numbers being picked, so we now go alternate columns. We will have to ignore, after picking a column, every fourth column after it so as to avoid the difference of $4$.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
\boxed{1} & 2 & \boxed{3} & 4 & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 \\ \hline
8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ \hline
\boxed{15} & 16 & \boxed{17} & 18 & 19 & \boxed{20} &  \\ 
\end{array}

Clearly we can pick now from the middlemost column and two more from second row.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
\boxed{1} & 2 & \boxed{3} & \boxed{4} & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 \\ \hline
8 & \boxed{9} & 10 & 11 & \boxed{12} & 13 & 14 \\ \hline
\boxed{15} & 16 & \boxed{17} & \boxed{18} & 19 & \boxed{20} &  \\ 
\end{array}

Logically, picking the consecutive $1,2,3,4$ shadows $5,6,7,8,9,10,11$ (meaning we cannot pick from this range) while picking the consecutive $17,18,19,20$ shadows $10,11,12,13,14,15,16$. So I tried to overlap the shadows (by choosing from first and third rows which overshadow middle row) and creating holes in them (by trying to pick from alternate columns) so as to allow maximum of elements to be picked.

Comment: Thank you so much! This style of recording the numbers helped a lot in understanding